# Dimension of an intersection.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a problem that if $U$ and $V$ are two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\dim(U)>n/2$, $\dim(V)>n/2$, show that $\dim(U\cap V)\geq 1$.

Now I know that 
$$\dim(U\cap V)=\dim(U)+\dim(V)-\dim(U+V)$$ 
but if I try to use this my reasoning gets me the following:
$$
\dim(U\cap V)\geq \frac{n}{2}+\frac{n}{2}-\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{n}{2}\right)=0
$$
I'm not sure if the dimension of $U+V$ is correctly deduced or if I can use this formula at all. Advice is appreciated.

Comment: It should be $>$ instead of $\geq$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U+V$ cannot exceed the whole space, and therefore $\dim(U+V)\leq n$. Therefore:
$$
\dim(U\cap V)>n/2+n/2-n=0
$$
which means $\dim(U\cap V)\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that the below bounds are *strict*, we obtain 
$$\dim(U\cap V)\gt n/2+n/2-\dim(U+V)=n-\dim(U+V)\geqslant 0$$
because $U+V\subset\mathbf R^n$. We thus have $\dim(U\cap V)\gt 0$, and this quantity is an integer hence it is strictly greater than $1$.